# passing a HANDLE to pipe from windows service to a user application

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services

I am writing a windows service which will communicate to a user level application. Windows service will run on user machine for 24/7, whenever a user launches a corresponding application, it will establish connection to service using a named-pipe. But here service is responsible for creating client-side named-pipe as well. All works well on server side, but I do not understand how to send the Handle created by service to the client process through SCM?

Comment: This question does not make much sense. What I can gather is, You have a service (running), and a client, that a user launches. When the client is launched, it creates a named pipe to communicate with the server.
This all makes sense. What I don't understand is, what client-side named-pipe is the service responsible for creating?

Comment: yes, you got it right. I want that my service create a named-pipe for the client and then it establish a connection with service. Can you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: If you read the tutorials at [Named Pipe Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365592(v=vs.85).aspx) they show how to implement the client, and server, sides of a named pipe

Comment: I want to implement the server side of the pipe in my windows service. can you tell me how do I debug this functionality in my service using VS 2k10?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't send the `HANDLE` over any IPC mechanism.  The best I can think of would be to pass the **name** of the named pipe (perhaps in a command line argument to the second program), and have the second program re-open that pipe.  That's the main purpose of the name.

Comment: Okey, Thank you! I am new to C++ development, Can you tell me how to establish a Session between this client and service process?

Comment: You've answered that question yourself: "whenever a user launches a corresponding application, it will establish connection to service using a named-pipe. "
Or is it actually the fundamental process by which a client connects to a named pipe created by a service process that is the problem?

Comment: Its also worth pointing out that this answer is technically wrong: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx) DuplicateHandle creates handles to use in IPC.

Comment: yes, multiple instances of client application need to communicate to the service using named-pipes. How can I do that?

Comment: Chris Becke, Sir you mean to say that I can create client-side Pipe by the service and then return this handle to the client.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to pass the handle, instead give the pipe a name and use that to access it by calling [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I am answering to question how to pass handle from one process to another, which is not what OP originally needed, and @AndersK is correct in regard to actual problem.

But this answer could be useful for others who actually want to pass HANDLE from one process to another.

You could use functions [DuplicateHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle) and [WSADuplicateSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaduplicatesocketw) (if your handle is a Socket).

But this seems really tricky in windows, and looks like you need to have high level of access to target process, but this must be possible, if is sending from Service to regular process, but I assume this isn't possible if you want to send handle from user process to more high privileged one(without compromising system's security).

After you duplicate handle -- you have handle value that is not usable inside your process, but you could send it as value to another process by any means (Pipes, SendMessage, Sockets, Clipboard, etc) and receiving process would be able to cast received BYTE[] to Handle and user it.

But this is actually hardcore code gymnastics, but it is doable. I don't have working example at hands.

Comment: Note that if your process runs as system you do have enough access. I've had this come up where I needed to pass a handle I was given so I couldn't create it.